# Typo3 DeepL 'No system languages found.'

Tags: typo3, deepl

I've been working on making my Typo3 11.5 powered site multi-language. To translate the bulk of my content elements I want to use DeepL via https://github.com/web-vision/wv_deepltranslate. While the manually translated pages are shown correctly in frontend, there is still some configuration missing as wv_deepltranslate is not working and its settings screen is showing 'No system languages found.'. The Deepl API Key and the Deepl API Url are set, the translate button is appearing when creating a translation, but pressing it only copies the content element in its original language. I have no clue what setting needs to be made to make the extension work and not show 'No system languages found.' anymore.
My relevant Typoscript setup is

```
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
[global]
```

and the site config says

```
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: 0
    websiteTitle: ''
  -
    title: English
    enabled: false
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: 1
```

Edit:
Fixed the 'No system languages found.' by creating the corresponding languages in the list menu on the page root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
config {
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
    linkVars = L(0-1)
    sys_language_uid = 0
}

[siteLanguage("locale") == "en_US.UTF-8"]
    config {
        language = en
        locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
        sys_language_uid = 1
    }
[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

Many TypoScript properties you're using are not existing anymore in TYPO3 Version 11. They have been removed in favor of the siteconfiguration.
See in the [Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87193-DeprecatedFunctionalityRemoved.html](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87193-DeprecatedFunctionalityRemoved.html?highlight=config%20language).
Also like @Robert included in his answer already the conditions did change and something like `[globalVar = GP:L = 1]` is not understood by TYPO3 anymore. Details about the new syntax you can find [in the TypoScript Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Conditions/Index.html), including a link to a more general explanation.

According to the documentation I doubt that the settings by TypoScript are required anyway, the configuration is done in a [special module](https://github.com/web-vision/wv_deepltranslate/blob/master/Documentation/UsersManual/Index.rst#deepl-module-settings).